# Call elasticsearch "_count" endpoint from spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, bigdata

Problem: calculate the number of records in elasticsearch filtered by date from spark

Please help to find how to call this endpoint directly from spark (2.4.0)

```
POST index_name.*/_count
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date_field_name": {
        "gte": "2021-02-09",
        "lte": "2021-02-09"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried the following solution but it's extremely slow since the calculation is done on spark side (not by elasticsearch) and the amount of data is quite big

```
val esQuery = f"""{
       "bool": {
           "filter": [
               {
               "range": {
                   "date_field_name": {
                       "gte": "2021-02-09",
                       "lte": "2021-02-09"
                    }
                }
            }
         ]
    }
}""".stripMargin
var df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("es").option("es.query", esQuery).load("index_name.*").select(col("date_field_name")).groupBy("date_field_name").count()
```

Comment: I too am facing the same problem. Can anyone please help. @author did you find the answer for this?